# How to add an id automatically to a related entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a OneToOne relation between 2 entities. One Molecule and one ConcGenotox (conclusion about genotoxicity).

I come from a page where all imformations about one Molecule are displayed and the id of the Molecule is in the address bar.

There is a button to edit a new ConcGenotox about this molecule witch id is always in the address bar.

My question is : How to add automatically the id from the molecule in the id_molecule relation of ConcGenotox when adding a new ConcGenotox ?

ConcGenotox Entity:

```
class ConcGenotox
{
    /**
     * @var \Molecule
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Molecule")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_molecule", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     *
     */
    private $idMolecule;
```

Molecule Entity :

```
class Molecule
{
   /**
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="NcstoxBundle\Entity\ConcGenotox", mappedBy="idMolecule")
    */
   private $concGenotox;
```

Contrôler:

```
/**
 * Creates a new concGenotox entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new/{id}", name="concgenotox_new")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function newAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $concGenotox = new Concgenotox();
    $form = $this->createForm('NcstoxBundle\Form\ConcGenotoxType', $concGenotox);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        var_dump($id);
        $concGenotox->setIdMolecule($id);
        $em->persist($concGenotox);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('concgenotox_show', array('id' => $concGenotox->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('concgenotox/new.html.twig', array(
        'concGenotox' => $concGenotox,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'id' => $id,
    ));
}
```

I tried to `->setIdMolecule($id)` but it give me an error :

```
Expected value of type "NcstoxBundle\Entity\Molecule" for association field "NcstoxBundle\Entity\ConcGenotox#$idMolecule", got "string" instead.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$molecule = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:Molecule')
                    ->find($id);

$concGenotox->setIdMolecule($molecule);
```

You need to set the entity not the Id

Comment: Glad to help you! Accept the answer to help other guys with your same problem

Comment: Done, there was a timer to accept the solution, you've been too quick to answer :)

Comment: If it bother you, just create an alias `setMolecule()` of `setIdMolecule()`

Answer (score 1):

Relationship property should be entity, not id.

Change:

```
class ConcGenotox
{
    /**
     * @var \Molecule
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Molecule")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_molecule", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     *
     */
    private $idMolecule;
```

to:

```
class ConcGenotox
{
    /**
     * @var \Molecule
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Molecule", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $molecule;
```

and change your action to:

```
/**
 * Creates a new concGenotox entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new/{molecule}", name="concgenotox_new")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function newAction(Request $request, Molecule $molecule)
{
    $concGenotox = new Concgenotox();
    $form = $this->createForm(ConcGenotoxType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $concGenotox = $form->getData();

        $molecule->setConcGenotox($concGenotox);

        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('concgenotox_show', array('id' => $concGenotox->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('concgenotox/new.html.twig', array(
        'concGenotox' => $concGenotox,
        'form'        => $form->createView(),
        'id'          => $id,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i'll change my relationship property from idMolecule to molecule

Comment: You have also some refactorings of your controller action in my answer.

Comment: Yes, i'll try it too. This could be a good training ... need to do the same with skinSensitization and systemicTox